# Is it possible to use variables in JSON and parse it with Python?

Tags: python, json

Is it possible to have a JSON file with `variable` something like below? This will be processed by python.

ver_file:

```
{
    "version":{
        "minor": 10,
        "major": 1.0.0.$minor
    }
}
```

so can I read it as below:

```
import json
with open(ver_file,"r") as vf:
    ver_config=json.load(vf)

 print(ver_config["version"]["major"])# I want this to print 1.0.0.10
```

I know I can concatenate major and minor with a dot, but I am working on a bigger problem where the variable usage can avoid duplicate info in json file and avoid concatenations in the python script.

Comment: No, it is not possible with the default JSON parser, but you could extend it yourself probably. Although this might get a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a feature of JSON.

There are various "JSON template" formats that provide functionality similar to this on top of JSON, and some of them have Python libraries, like [`jsontemplate`](https://pypi.org/project/jsontemplate/) and [`JSON-template`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-template/) and another one I can't remember the name of that's based on JSON5 and will allow certain kinds of variable expressions that would be legal as JS source code… But whether any of them do exactly what you want (and have stable, maintained libraries that you can use out of the box), I have no idea.

Or, of course, you can design your own format and implement it yourself.